# Most efficient way to do this slice based multiplication in Tensorflow

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, slice

I'm trying to perform an operation of multiplying a slice of a 2D matrix by a constant.

For example, if i wanted to multiply everything but the first 2 columns

To perform this in numpy, one could do:

```
a = np.array([[0,7,4],
              [1,6,4],
              [0,2,4],
              [4,2,7]])
a[:, 2:] = 2.0*a[:, 2:]

>> a
>> array([[ 0,  7,  8],
          [ 1,  6,  8],
          [ 0,  2,  8],
          [ 4,  2, 14]])
```

However, at least from what i've searched, tensorflow currently doesn't have a straightforward way to do this.

My current solution is to create **a** originally as two separate Tensors a1 and a2, multiply the second one by 2.0 and then concatenate them across axis=1. The operation is simple enough that this is possible. However I have two questions

1. Is that the most efficient way to do this
2. Is there a better (general/efficient) way to perform this to bring the functionality closer to numpy's slicing magic (perhaps https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/scatter_

Answer (score 4):

One option is to perform entrywise multiplication, as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.Variable(initial_value=[[0,7,4],[1,6,4],[0,2,4],[4,2,7]])
b = tf.mul(a,[1,1,2])

s=tf.InteractiveSession()
s.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
b.eval()
```

This prints

```
array([[ 0,  7,  8],
       [ 1,  6,  8],
       [ 0,  2,  8],
       [ 4,  2, 14]])
```

More generally, if `a` has more columns, you can do something like that:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.Variable(initial_value=[[0,7,4],[1,6,4],[0,2,4],[4,2,7]])
b = tf.mul(a,[1,1]+[2 for i in range(a.get_shape()[1]-2)])

s=tf.InteractiveSession()
s.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
b.eval()
```

Or if your matrix has many columns you could replace

```
b = tf.mul(a,[1,1]+[2 for i in range(a.get_shape()[1]-2)])
```

with

```
import numpy as np
b = tf.mul(a,np.concatenate((np.array([1,1]),2*np.ones(a.get_shape()[1]-2))))
```

Comment: Hey Miriam, thanks for that option. How would one generalize this to a variable 2nd dimension? I.e. if a.shape = (N,D). One would need to define [1,1,2,2,2,2......2]

Comment: @miriamfaber thanks for the update! it looks good (although tf.mul is tf.matmul)  

I'm wondering is there any reason you are using numpy for the constant array as opposed to tensorflow equivalents

Comment: @undercurrent you can use tf.ones as well, I just forgot it exists. Note that tf.matmul and tf.mul are not the same. The former is the usual matrix multiplication, while the latter is an entrywise product. In my answer I used the latter

Comment: aha, thanks for the clarification. re: matmul (oops!) I meant to write tf.multiply()